# Regex expression for specific format

Tags: regex, validation, jira

Hello everyone sorry maybe is a stupid question but I need a regex expression with the next format:

**APP-xxxx** and **COM-xxxx**

But in the same expression. I don’t find if is possible to add “or” in the expression. And not empty (The “x” is a numeric and is allow “xxx” and “xxxx”)

Please help. Thank in advance.

Kind regards.

Comment: This is what the [alternative operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) is for. So something like `(APP|COM)-\d{3,4}` would fit what you've described. Also how is this question related in any way to validation or Jira? When you add tags please make sure to give a good explanation as to why they're there.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your quick response. I have added “Jira” and “validation” because I want to use this in a Regular Expression Check Validator in the workflow inside jira. Tomorrow I will try the expressions you mention. Thank you very much.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't related to your problem, I'm asking how it's related to the question. Asking a question about a regular expression that just happens to be being used in Jira does not justify using the Jira tag. If you were having an issue with, let's say, JQL then that would be different, because that's specific to Jira. The validation tag is also questionable because validation, in a sense, is a core part of RegEx. I don't personally think either of these tags add anything to the question.

Comment: @jesse - It can be pretty hard to figure out how much and what kind of information is needed/desired when asking a question. Given that there is no standard for regex, it's actually pretty relevant that the OP would give the context in which they were using the regex. I've used tools that have their own regex dialects where your pattern would not have worked.

Comment: From the regex tag wiki: "_Specify the language (PHP, Python, etc) or tool (grep, VS Code, Google Analytics, etc) that you are using._"

Comment: @JDB Regex in and of itself is a standard. Sure there are variations of it, but there are certain elements that are always there. The expression I provided in particular is made up of very basic parts that are outlined in the standard. If the tool you're referencing doesn't adhere to the regex standard, then is it really regex?

Comment: @jesse - I use "standard" in the formal sense: a governing body which publishes and maintains standards to which most authors adhere or at least consider. The HTML standard is maintained by WHATWG (previously, W3C). The JavaScript standard is maintained by Ecma International. There is no such standardization body or group for Regex. We certainly have adhoc standards (for example the Kleene star, `*`, for repetition), but there is no generally accepted standard by which to measure or critique regex. The closest we have is Perl (thus "Perl-compatible regex")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not personally used Jira Workflow Validators, but my best guess as to which feature you are using led me to this documentation page:

[JSU Automation Suite for Jira Workflows - Server Version:
Regular Expression Check Validator](https://beecom-products.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JSU/pages/25680565/Regular+Expression+Check+Validator)

If you are using the server version, then it appears that the Regular Expression is evaluated by Java, as evidenced by their recommendation to test your regex using a [Java Regular Expression Tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html). That site also includes some basic documentation as well as many examples.

The expression you would most likely find helpful has already been offered in the comments:

```
(APP|COM)-\d{3,4}
```

Which means:

- **`(APP|COM)`** :: `APP` or `COM` (case sensitive)
- **`-`** :: A literal `-` character
- **`\d{3,4}`** :: A digit (`\d`) repeated 3-4 times

The last part has a few alternatives which you can use depending on preference:

`\d` is basically the same as `[0-9]` (match one character from `0` to `9`)

`\d{3,4}` could also be expressed as:

- `\d+` meaning one or more digits (if you don't care have many digits there are, as long as there's at least one)
- `\d{3,}` meaning three or more digits
- `\d\d\d\d?` meaning three digits following be a fourth optional digit (the `?`)